# Finite intersection property for sets containing generating elements of derived subgroups of quotients

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, p-groups, pro-p-groups

What I need to prove is a consequence of the following theorem.

> **Theorem A.** Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and suppose that its derived subgroup $G'$ is generated by 2 elements. Then there exists $x\in G$ s.t.
>   $$ K_x(G):=\{[x,g]\mid g\in G \}=G'. $$

Now let $G$ be a pro-$p$ group whose derived subgroup is topologically generated by 2 elements. Define for any open normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ the set
$$X_N:=\{x\in G\mid K_{xN}(G/N)=(G/N)'\}. $$
Notice that since $G$ is pro-$p$, every open normal subgroup of $G$ has finite index, therefore we can apply Theorem A to $G/N$ and conclude that $X_N\ne \emptyset$ for all $N\trianglelefteq_o G$.

What I need to prove is that the family $\{X_N\}_{N\trianglelefteq_o G}$ has the finite intersection property.

My guess is that we can take two any open normal subgroups $N$, $M$ of $G$, consider their product $NM$ which is still normal and open (since their product is equal to the union of cosets of an open subgroup) and prove that $$X_N\cap X_M \supseteq X_{NM}.$$
Since $NM\trianglelefteq_o G$, $X_{NM}$ would be non-empty and the statement would be proved.

All of this comes from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.10422) (at page 2 you can find Theorem A, as well as Theorem B whose proof, at page 11, is what I'm interested in). Notice that the author says that it's clear that $\{X_N\}_{N\trianglelefteq_o G}$ has the finite intersection property, so there could be an easier way to prove that.